# Perform a sub query on an Array of strings that comes back from result in SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query

```
SELECT colors, car, FROM inventory
```

where colors is data type of ARRAY and car is data type VARCHAR

it returns this

```
|   colors             |      car    |
|["red",blue,"green"]  |   "mustang" |
```

I want to join each item from the colors ARRAY  on a different table. For example, the price based on color are in a table called in `prices`

```
SELECT * FROM prices
|   color             |      price    |
|   "red"             |      300000   |
|   "green"           |      500000   |
|   "blue"            |      100000   |
```

How can I join on a table with a result that returns an ARRAY

Answer (score 2):

Using [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html) as join condition:

> Returns True if the specified variant is found in the specified array.

```
SELECT *
FROM Inventory i
JOIN prices p
  ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(p.color::variant, i.colors)
```